# Minimum Network Accessibility for IIS Web Server

Tags: security, iis, networking

I work in a very large, bureaucratic organization and I'm trying to pitch a simple (local) web interface to my team. Given extensive firewall and domain security, I am wondering if this is even possible.

My question is: From a network security perspective, what might prevent IIS from allowing connections from other users on my network?

I believe IIS uses port 80 for default traffic, but it isn't listed as "Listening" when I run netstat -a through command prompt. I do have other ports listening but my fear is they are strictly monitored. Our organization also restricts connectivity between users to shared directories, so I'm wondering if that impacts anything like Windows Authentication in IIS.

I have very little network security experience so thank you in advance to anyone who can shed some light on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what might prevent IIS from allowing connections from other users on my network?

- local firewall (GPO)
- more GPOs regarding IIS or services in general
- switch ACLs
- switch port privacy
- firewall rules

If your company has a network service policy you shouldn't try to circumvent it. It might put your job in danger.

Comment: Thanks Zac this is what I was looking for. I'm not trying to go around the policy I just needed context for what it might consist of so I can ask the right questions.